# Closed Parent tab using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using following javascript code to closed parent window using popup's button, but i dont know what is wrong in this code, why it is not working...

```
function closewindow() {
    if (confirm("Thank You. You May Close The Window.")) {
        close();
        window.top.close();
        window.parent.close();
        var win = window.open("", "_self"); /* url = “” or “about:blank”; target=”_self” */
        win.close();
        window.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: Long story short: [a window can only be closed if it was opened by Javascript using window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close).  Targeting `"_self"` doesn't make a window a viable close target.

Comment: Push F12 to see the error messages. they should show "Access denied" which is correct. You should never be allowed to close a window you did not open yourself. IE does have a hack where overwriting the name of the window will allow closing it. I hope they fixed it. Please refrain from trying to close our windows or we will never come back to your website